# How to create folders according to date in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, crontab

Is there any other short/easier and smarter way to do the following in Linux?

```
cd /home/abcd/dammi
mkdir $(date +%Y-%m)
cd $(date +%Y-%m)
mkdir $(date +%d)
# RESULT : /home/abcd/dammi/2011-05/26
cd /home/wxyz/harrami
mkdir $(date +%Y-%m)
cd $(date +%Y-%m)
mkdir $(date +%d)
cd /home/abcd/harrami
mkdir $(date +%Y-%m)
cd $(date +%Y-%m)
mkdir $(date +%d)
cd /home/wxyz/harrami
mkdir $(date +%Y-%m)
cd $(date +%Y-%m)
mkdir $(date +%d)
```

I need to use crontab to create folders every day and every month inside /home/abcd/dammi, /home/abcd/harrami, /home/wxyz/dammi and /home/wxyz/harrami. Can anyone help me with this?

Info:

```
    GROUPS : USERS
--------------------
    abcd  : abcd
    wxyz  : dammi, harrami
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOME_DIRS="/home/abcd/dammi /home/wxyz/harrami /home/abcd/harrami /home/wxyz/harrami"
DATE_DIR=$(date +%Y-%m)
DAY_DIR=$(date +%d)

for FOLDER in $HOME_DIRS; do
    mkdir -p "${FOLDER}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"
done
```

Well, of course you could also do it without `DATE_DIR` and `DAY_DIR` variables but this algorithm makes sure the date is not generated many times which is faster and assures the date to be the same for all users (even if you start it right before midnight and the last directory is created after midnight).

You might also have to think about enhancing the script using chown in order to allow users to write to the newly created directories.

Edit:
If you want to create the same folder structure within two `/home` sub-folders you might combine the script of RolKau with my one:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_LIST="dammi harrami"
HOME_SUBDIRS="abcd wxyz"
DATE_DIR=$(date +%Y-%m)
DAY_DIR=$(date +%d)

for HOME_SUBDIR in $HOME_SUBDIRS; do
    for U in $USER_LIST; do
        mkdir -p "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"
    done
done
```

Edit2:
I assume the user list contains the user names. So let's extend the script so the directory owner is changed properly as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_LIST="dammi harrami"
HOME_SUBDIRS="abcd wxyz"
DATE_DIR=$(date +%Y-%m)
DAY_DIR=$(date +%d)

for HOME_SUBDIR in $HOME_SUBDIRS; do
    for U in $USER_LIST; do
        mkdir -p "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"
        chown -R "${U}" "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}"
    done
done
```

Edit3:
To change the ownership I think the easiest way is to read the ownership from the directory at `/home/<subdir>/<user>`

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_LIST="dammi harrami"
HOME_SUBDIRS="abcd wxyz"
DATE_DIR=$(date +%Y-%m)
DAY_DIR=$(date +%d)

for HOME_SUBDIR in $HOME_SUBDIRS; do
    for U in $USER_LIST; do
        mkdir -p "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"
        GROUP_MEMBER=$(stat -c %G "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}")
        chown -R "${U}":"${GROUP_MEMBER}" "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}"
    done
done
```

Sure you could use stat as well to read the owner; but it's slightly slower than just reading it from the variable - as you asked for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_LIST="dammi harrami"
HOME_SUBDIRS="abcd wxyz"
DATE_DIR=$(date +%Y-%m)
DAY_DIR=$(date +%d)

for HOME_SUBDIR in $HOME_SUBDIRS; do
    for U in $USER_LIST; do
        mkdir -p "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"
        OWNER=$(stat -c %U "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}")
        GROUP_MEMBER=$(stat -c %G "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}")
        chown -R "${OWNER}":"${GROUP_MEMBER}" "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}"
    done
done
```

Edit4:
Alternative solution using hard-coded group membership.

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_LIST="dammi:group1 harrami:group2"
HOME_SUBDIRS="abcd wxyz"
DATE_DIR=$(date +%Y-%m)
DAY_DIR=$(date +%d)

for HOME_SUBDIR in $HOME_SUBDIRS; do
    for UG in $USER_LIST; do
        G=${UG##*:}
        U=${UG%%:*}
        mkdir -p "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"
        GROUP_MEMBER=$(stat -c %G "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}")
        chown -R "${U}":"${G}" "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}"
    done
done
```

Edit5:
Looking at your initial post the desired structure might be slightly different. I guess you want to have a sub-directory in `/home` for each group and only add user-directories for each group member. So here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_LIST="dammi:abcd dammi:wxyz harrami:wxyz"
DATE_DIR=$(date +%Y-%m)
DAY_DIR=$(date +%d)

for UG in $USER_LIST; do
    G=${UG##*:}
    U=${UG%%:*}
    mkdir -p "/home/${G}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"
    chown -R "${U}":"${G}" "/home/${G}/${U}/${DATE_DIR}"
done
```

If a user is member in multiple groups just specify it multiple times in USER_LIST.

Comment: @SkyBeam yes the permission is causing problem now. how do i overcome it?

Comment: Just add another chown line - I've updated the answer to include chown as well. I guess you won't have to change the group ownership. If you have to, then just use 'chwon -R "${U}":groupname ...' instead.

Comment: @SkyBeam I have two different groups for those two users. Should I do it separately for this adding another for loop?

Comment: @SkyBeam actually there are three users and two group. I added in question above about that.

Comment: Although this looks easy it is probably a bit more difficult to answer as you would have to map each user to a group. However as we are talking about home directories most likely the /home/<subdir>/<user> directory already belongs to the right group. So we mighr read it from there? I am going to add an update...

Comment: @SkyBeam: I think you misspelled part of your code: `mkdir -p "${FOLDER}/${DATE_DIR}/${DA_DIR}"` should be `mkdir -p "${FOLDER}/${DATE_DIR}/${DAY_DIR}"`.  Basically you forgot a "Y"

Comment: @SkyBeam it means I also can do $(stat -c %U "/home/${HOME_SUBDIR}/${U}") in the place of ${U}?

Comment: I've just added another variant in "Edit4" which allows you to hard-code user AND group in USER_LIST variable, separated by colon.

Comment: sure you can use stat as well to get the user name, but the user name is already available (assuming it's identical to the directory name) so no need to read it from file system (which is slower than reading it from existing variable). And yes, I might have misspelled some of my code. I did not execute it; it might need some debugging ;) - I've just added some code snipplet in Edit3 as well using stat to retrieve owner.

Comment: @SkyBeam OK I will be using the hard-coded group membership solution. Thank you so much for your time and work. You really helped me a lot in this. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Well, looking at your edit on the initial post your goal might be slightly different. Currently the script creates ALL the user folders within all defined home subdirs. Looking at your table you might want to have only one sub-directory at /home which refers to the group and then only sub-directories for group members. I will add a snippet for this too.

Comment: OK, this was likely my last edit for today. I did answer your question on how to copy files to these directories as well: http://superuser.com/questions/289154/how-to-move-around-files-using-ls-al-result-in-linux

Comment: You can also get away with only one 'date' invocation: `$(date "+%Y-%M/%d")`

Comment: @glenn: yeeeessss, right. But I need the YYYY-MM notation for the top-level directory in chown call in order to assure that also this directory belongs to the user.

Comment: @SkyBeam, multiple invocations of `date` in such a manner should never be done due to a theoretical risk of date change. If you need the date-level directory, you can always append `/..`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-p` option to mkdir to create more than one element of the path at the time, and use a for-loop to avoid repeating yourself:

```
sh -c '
  for a in abcd wxyz; do 
    for b in dammi harrami; do 
      mkdir -p /home/$a/$b/$(date +%Y-%m)/$(date +%d); 
    done; 
  done
'
```

(line-breaks to show logical structure; could be all on one line)

Comment: Good answer. Even a bit faster than me. I like that you loop over home sub-directories too. However in his sample he creates 3 times "harrami" subfolders but dammi is not created within "wxyz" folder. Well, this might be a bug in the initial question though. You might also want to move the $(date) calls out of the loop. The date call is supposed to return the same value for each loop. $() issues a fork which can be very slow when used in loops.

Comment: You can also get away with only one 'date' invocation: `$(date "+%Y-%M/%d")`

Comment: Multiple invocations of `date` are bad and should never be done due to a risk of date change. A theoretical bug is still very much a bug.